# rstudio corrupted letter and number in plot

Tags: r, conda

I got this problem with Rstudio, the plot labels are replaced by squares with 4 numbers inside.

[image]

Anyone has some idea what caused this trouble? I tried to re-create conda env and install rstudio, not working. And I got no such issue if i use basic R.

Thanks in advance

update 28.07.2020:

I tried to install rstudio via conda for a new account, the issue reproduced.
I tried to install rstudio via conda on a second PC, the issue persisted.

I tried to install an older version of rstudio via conda, and conda went to forever "solving environment".

I think it might be an issue of conda recipie....

update 29.07.2020 :

Problem solved by specifying the font family in plot function

```
plot(1,2,family="Times New Roman")
```

But the R default font

```
plot(1,2,family="mono")
plot(1,2,family="sans")
```

reproduce the same issue. It seems like conda caused R unloaded default font.

Comment: Please add data using `dput`. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: That seems like a graphics device or fonts not loaded/found issue.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you. I will look at those directions

Comment: This seems like a conda issue since it doesn't happen with basic R; I've added that tag.  But you're going to need to add enough details to make it reproducible if you want help fixing it.

Comment: Issue solved. Please close this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed [Helvetica.ttf.gz](http://laplace.physics.ubc.ca/Doc/rnpletal/Helvetica.ttf.gz) on my ubuntu and those gibberish went away.